# How do I modify slider code counter?

Tags: jquery, slider, counter

I have a content slider, and the counter for the content slider updates based on using cnt.text(i+1+' / '+amount); But instead of it displaying a numerical counter, I would like for it to show bullets instead, with an active class being assigned.

Here is a jsfiddle of the below: http://jsfiddle.net/REn8C/2/

HTML for the slider is:

```
<div class="homepageslider_imageholder">
    <ul id="sliderbannerlist" class="homepageslider_imageslist">
        <li class="acslide slide1" style="">
            <div class="acslidecontainer">
                SLIDE 1 HERE
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="acslide slide2" style="display: none;">
            <div class="acslidecontainer">
                SLIDE 2 HERE
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="acslide slide3" style="display: none;">
            <div class="acslidecontainer">
                SLIDE 3 HERE
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="acslide slide4" style="display: none;">
            <div class="acslidecontainer">
                SLIDE 4 HERE
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Slide Pager: Start -->
    <div id="slidecounter" class="homepageslider_pagerholder">
        <ul class="homepageslider_pagerlist">
            <li><span></span></li>
            <li class="active"><span></span></li>
            <li><span></span></li>
            <li><span></span></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Slide Pager: End -->

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
div.homepageslider {}
div.homepageslider_holder {}
    div.homepageslider_inner {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 929px;
        height: 318px;
        border: 9px solid #fff;
        background: #d7c288;

        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        -moz-box-shadow:    0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        box-shadow:         0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        }

        /* Navigation */
        div.homepageslider_nav {
            position: absolute;
            top: 35px;
            right: 0;
            z-index: 50;
            width: 155px;
            }
            ul.homepageslider_navlist {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                list-style-type: none;
                }
                ul.homepageslider_navlist li {
                    margin: 0 0 3px !important;
                    display: block;
                    width: 155px;
                    height: 25px;
                    font-size: 12px;
                    letter-spacing: -0.75px;
                    line-height: auto;
                    list-style-type: none;
                    }
                    ul.homepageslider_navlist a {
                        padding: 0 0 0 12px;
                        display: block;
                        height: 25px;
                        color: #fff;
                        text-decoration: none !important;
                        text-transform: uppercase;
                        background-color: #736056;

                        text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #40352f;
                        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
                        -moz-transition:    all 0.3s ease-in-out;
                        -ms-transition:     all 0.3s ease-in-out;
                        -o-transition:      all 0.3s ease-in-out;
                        transition:         all 0.3s ease-in-out;
                        }
                        ul.homepageslider_navlist a:hover {
                            background-color: #40352f;
                            }
                        ul.homepageslider_navlist span {
                            display: block;
                            height: 25px;
                            line-height: 25px;
                            }

        /* Image Holder */
        div.homepageslider_imageholder {
            position: relative;
            z-index: 40;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 929px;
            height: 318px;
            }
            ul#sliderbannerlist {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                list-style-type: none;
                }
                ul#sliderbannerlist li.acslide {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    z-index: 5;
                    width: 929px;
                    height: 318px;
                    list-style-type: none;
                    }
                    ul#sliderbannerlist div.acslidecontainer {
                        width: 929px;
                        height: 318px;
                        }
                        ul#sliderbannerlist img {}

            /* Pager Holder */
            div.homepageslider_pagerholder {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 50%;
                z-index: 50;
                margin: 0 0 0 -40px;
                padding: 0 9px;
                height: 22px;
                background-color: #fff;
                }
                ul.homepageslider_pagerlist {
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    list-style-type: none;
                    }
                    ul.homepageslider_pagerlist li {
                        margin: 7px 5px 0;
                        padding: 0;
                        display: block;
                        float: left;
                        width: 8px;
                        height: 8px;
                        list-style-type: none;
                        }
                        ul.homepageslider_pagerlist li.active {}
                        ul.homepageslider_pagerlist span {
                            display: block;
                            width: 8px;
                            height: 8px;
                            cursor: pointer;
                            background-color: #89c2b2;

                            -webkit-border-radius:  5px;
                            -moz-border-radius:     5px;
                            border-radius:          5px;
                            }
                            ul.homepageslider_pagerlist li.active span {
                                background-color: #595656;
                                }
```

The plugin for the slider is:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.acSlider = function(interval) {
        var slides;
        var cnt;
        var amount;
        var i;

        function run() {
            // Hiding previous slide and showing next
            $(slides[i]).fadeOut(1000);
            i++;
            if (i >= amount) i = 0;
            $(slides[i]).fadeIn(1000);

            // Updating Counter
            cnt.text(i+1+' / '+amount);

            // Loop
            setTimeout(run, interval);
        }

        slides  = $('#sliderbannerlist').children();
        cnt     = $('#slidecounter');
        amount  = slides.length;
        i=0;

        // Updating Counter
        cnt.text(i+1+' / '+amount);

        setTimeout(run, interval);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Right now, since there are 4 slides, what will be added for the counter inside #slidecounter is 1/4, 2/4, 3/4, 4/4. Instead, I would like to use what I have in my HTML for the counter, with the class changing to the active bullet:

```
    <!-- Slide Pager: Start -->
    <div id="slidecounter" class="homepageslider_pagerholder">
        <ul class="homepageslider_pagerlist">
            <li><span></span></li>
            <li class="active"><span></span></li>
            <li><span></span></li>
            <li><span></span></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Slide Pager: End -->
```

How do I modify the jQuery plugin so that the counter is modified to work the way I want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are going to want to create the code that generates the bullets. Something such as:

```
for (z = 0; z < amount; z++) {
    $(".homepageslider_pagerlist").append('<li><span></span></li>');
}
```

Then you are going to want some code to append a new active class:

```
$(".homepageslider_pagerlist li").eq(i - 1).addClass('active');
```

Note the subtraction of 1. This is because the eq selector is 0 based

[A little JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/35Fyf/)

EDIT: You'll also want to remove the class from the other li's. Pretty simple, just use removeClass('active')

Comment: Thanks for your response Hodson. I'm well ahead of you on using removeClass :) Thanks so much for your solution. I implemented it just minutes after your post and it worked great! Thanks again!